# how to remove the alsa driver from linux kernel

Tags: linux, alsa

I have taken reference alsa driver from 
https://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Minivosc and driver code path from https://github.com/stadaki/alsa-minivosc-src .

If I, do a rmmod of aforesaid driver using below command

"rmmod snd-minivosc"

Output of the above command is

"rmmod: ERROR: Module snd_minivosc is in use"

Below is output from lsmod | grep snd-minivosc

"snd_minivosc           16384  1

snd_pcm  98304  6 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_minivosc,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi

snd                    81920  26 
snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_usb_audio,snd_minivosc,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_pcm"

Is there is any way to remove alsa driver from kernel without restarting PC?

Comment: Close the program that is accessing the device. Check for open files in `/dev/snd/`.

Comment: @CL, No program is accessing the device except audio core module such as snd, snd-pcm, snd-timer and so on. Kindly let me know any procedure to remove alsa driver from linux kernel.  output of /dev/snd is given below total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root      320 Jun 21 16:21 ./
drwxr-xr-x  19 root root     4220 Jun 21 16:21 ../
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root      100 Jun 21 16:21 by-path/
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  2 Jun 21 16:16 controlC0
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116,  7 Jun 21 16:16 controlC2
crw-rw----+  1 root audio 116, 13 Jun 21 16:17 controlC3
and pcmC3D0c

Comment: Checking for open files is done with `lsof` or `fuser`.

Comment: lsof output is given below  lsof /dev/snd/controlC3
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND     PID         USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
pulseaudi 30936 test-uhdc-t3   43u   CHR 116,13      0t0  422 /dev/snd/controlC3

Comment: And "pulseaudio" is "no program"?

Comment: @Cl, did you try removing alsa driver from linux kernel..?

Comment: Any one knows what is procedure to remove alsa module from linux kernel. I'm working with x86 architecture and I want to remove alsa module from x86 PC.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum. And your actual program is how to terminate PulseAudio, which is not a programming question.